# Converting nested List to Dictionary | Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, random, list-comprehension

I have made a `list comprehension` that generates mock fingerprint data.

```
import random

val = [[hand, [digit, [[random.randint(1, 250) for i in range(0, 8)] for j in range(0, 4)]]] for hand in ['Left', 'Right'] for digit in ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Little']]
val
>>> [['Left',
  ['Thumb',
   [[247, 115, 74, 161, 47, 31, 231, 34],
    [246, 52, 1, 160, 196, 65, 4, 118],
    [128, 219, 128, 140, 207, 2, 156, 226],
    [127, 61, 56, 151, 169, 122, 117, 105]]]]
...
 ['Right',
  ['Thumb',
   [[229, 222, 138, 230, 86, 119, 201, 209],
    [106, 238, 191, 15, 214, 134, 77, 145],
    [186, 174, 81, 143, 138, 5, 54, 148],
    [176, 85, 205, 235, 228, 204, 91, 17]]]]
```

Note: "digit" means finger name.

Based on this list output, I would like to convert it to a dictionary of the below structure.

I've been unable to make a `dictionary comprehension` that would yield the desired output:

```
{
  "Left":
  {
    "Thumb": [...],
    "Index": [...],
    "Middle": [...],
    "Ring": [...],
    "Little": [...]
  },
  "Right":
  {
    "Thumb": [...],
    "Index": [...],
    "Middle": [...],
    "Ring": [...],
    "Little": [...]
  }
}
```

Note: I understand my above dictionary "output" is somewhat incorrect.

---

I'm using `Jupyter Notebooks`. Best attempt:

```
output = {hand: {digit: matrix for i in val for hand in val[i] for digit in hand}}
output
>>> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-500095a8cf85> in <module>
----> 1 output = {hand: {digit: matrix for i in val for hand in val[i] for digit in hand}}
      2 output

NameError: name 'hand' is not defined
```

Comment: I am also confusing myself with json and dictionary. It is dictionary I am interested in.

Comment: `val = {hand: {digit: [random.randint(1, 250) for i in range(0, 8)] for digit in ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Little']} for hand in ['Left', 'Right']}`? Or do you want to convert the current structure to a `dict` of `dict` of `list`?

Comment: Your solution is perfect! Thank you so much. It means one less step as well. Make that an answer and I'll hit accept. If I write it, I have to wait 2 days to accept it is why. Tysm again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create the structure directly with a `dict` comprehension.

```
import random
output = {
    hand: {
        digit: [
            random.randint(1, 250) for _ in range(0, 8)
        ] for digit in ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Little']
    } for hand in ['Left', 'Right']
}
print(output)
```

The trick to nested comprehensions is to create your inner-most structure first and work outwards from there.

So create your inner `list`,

```
inner = [random.randint(1, 250) for _ in range(0, 8)]
```

Then your `dict` of digits.

```
digits = {digit: inner for digit in ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Little']}
```

And lastly your `dict` of hands.

```
hands = {hand: digits for hand in ['Left', 'Right']}
```

Combine those all together and you get.

```
{
    hand: {
        digit: [
            random.randint(1, 250) for _ in range(0, 8)
        ] for digit in ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Little']
    } for hand in ['Left', 'Right']
}
```

Comment: "create your inner-most structure first and work outwards from there." That's the insight I needed. Ty